# I have to add .aar files as a library in a sub project in Android studio. It gives me an error.

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have added the .aar files to libs folder in the sub-project.
And have given the repositories as:

```
repositories {
 mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
```

in the build.gradle of this sub-project.
Do I need to add dependencies in Main project's build.gradle also?
If yes, how should that be done?

Answer (score 8):

In the repositories of your module: app

```
repositories {

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Add the following in the dependencies of your module: app
In the case that your have both a JAR and an AAR file, do the following.

```
dependencies 
{
  implementation (name: '***library name***', ext: 'aar')
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], )

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the dependencies too:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
```

This can be done in the subprojects build.gradle.

---

Edit: You might need to specify the file itself:

```
compile(name:'name-of-file',ext:'aar')
```

Comment: Did that. Didn't help.

Comment: His solution works ok, `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])` this will link all libraries (*.jar or *.aar) to your project or you can use manual link for every lib. If it doesn't work for then it's your fault

Answer (score 3):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

1. File -> New Module -> Import JAR/AAR Package
2. "File name" select .aar file，
   example:

```
d:/myproject/mylib/build/outputs/aar/mylib-release.aar
```

3. "Subproject name",example:

   ```
   mylib-release
   ```
4. /app/build.gradle

   dependencies{

   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

   compile project(':mylib-release')

   }

Answer (score 3):

For `filename.aar`

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'filename', ext:'aar')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a aar file in libs folder.
The aar file doesn't contain the dependencies, then you have to add these dependencies also in the main project.

In your `module1/build.gradle` you should have something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1') //for example
    //..
 }
```

In your `mainModule/build.gradle` you have to add all the dependencies used by your module1.

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile(name:'fileName',ext:'aar')
        compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1') //for example
        //...
     }
```