# constraintlayout attributes in aar not recognised while buildling

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-constraintlayout, android-library

I have created a library which has a dependency on constraintlayout. This library is included in a new project via aar file. The project gives following error for all its appNS attributes used.

> home/vishal/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/my_library.aar/9012247ff26b45ffb7af7d608db342c5/res/layout/activity_main.xml:70:
>   AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf (aka
>   com.example.sampleapp:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf) not found.

Library compile sdk : 28
support version : 28.0.0

ConstraintLayout is added as **implementation** in library. The aar library is included in project as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/my_library.aar')
}
```

I have tried converting the library & project to androidX but the problem persists.

### **Note:**

**In order to test scenario with existing libraries [Update]:**
I added constraint layout in scratch card library [ https://github.com/Veeshal/scratchCardLayout ] along with an activity & its layout implementing the constraint layout. Imported it as aar file. I did not receive any error while building.
To verify create a sample project and add the generated AAR file from the module **scratchcardlayout** inside the github repository shared above.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    .....

    <!-- Optional Design -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        ....

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- Selected Design -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_cropping_layer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        ....

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    .....

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Transitive dependencies are not included in the aar, if you want them to be included automatically in your app you could publish the aar as a maven artifact though

Comment: The library is not suppose to be available publicly so cannot put it in maven. Only aar can be shared.

Comment: I think you don't need to publish publicly, you should be able to "publish" it locally, check [this article](https://android.jlelse.eu/local-maven-repository-and-libraries-updated-story-7585f1563fb2)

Comment: So if I share the aar file to someone else then they need to have it locally as well. Now they have to manually save it to local .m2/repository folder. Am I right ? Isn't there a work around.

Comment: Yes that's inconvenient indeed, you could try something like jitpack.io, it's free for public github repos but has a paid feature for private ones.

Comment: @Veeshal can u put the constraint layout dependency in your app module and try once

Comment: @Raghavendra it works if dependency is added in app module. But in most library such dependencies are not required to be added in app module. It should've resolved by itself.

Comment: @Veeshal I may be wrong here if u make the dependency as *api* rather than *implementation* in the library it may be resolve itself I think?

Comment: @Raghavendra I have tried with 'api' as well instead of 'implementation' but it didn't work.

Comment: @lelloman I have updated the question. Please check Note section at the bottom.

Comment: @Veeshal maybe compare the claim you've added with what I've answered... something does not fit.

Comment: @Veeshal the link you posted is broken, the answer to your question is that aar do not contain transitive dependencies, you either include them forcefully (very bad) or you use a managed dependency with a maven artifact

Comment: @lelloman The link contained ] at the end causing it to be shown as broken. I have updated the link. I used this library and added activity with ConstraintLayout as root. I generated the aar file & included it the same way as the aar I mentioned in this post to test out & it worked. If you want I can share that part of code in github.

Comment: I checked the library, it doesn't have any dependency on ConstraintLayout...?

Comment: @lelloman you can check this out. https://github.com/Veeshal/scratchCardLayout . The aar generated via this is working correctly without any issues in any sample project.

Comment: Transitive dependencies are not included in the aar and it is intended to be so, you either declare the transitive dependencies explicitly in the app that's using the aar or you publish the aar as a maven artifact so that the transitive dependencies are declared in the pom file. The aar generated by the project you posted does not include ConstraintLayout, if it's working with other sample apps it means that the sample apps already have that dependency (like the demo app in the project itself).

Comment: btw that repo is published as maven artifact on bintray...check the [pom file](https://bintray.com/skymansandy/ScratchCard/download_file?file_path=in%2Fcodeshuffle%2Fscratchcardlayout%2FScratchCardLayout%2F1.0.4%2FScratchCardLayout-1.0.4.pom)

Comment: @lelloman I agree regarding transitive dependency. I have searched through internet & got the same answer. But I am not able to understand why it worked with the library. I know its published as an artifact. But I am not importing it as an artifact. This is what is added in the sample project as dependency::::: dependencies { implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs') implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' implementation files('libs/scratchcardlayout.aar') implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0' }

Comment: run `./gradlew dependencies` in the app where you're using the aar, you should be able to see which dependency is importing ConstraintLayout.

Comment: OMG I got why it was working. Layout file name of library and sample app was same so it got replaced and constraint layout was not required at all by the sample app.

Comment: all's well that ends well :)

Comment: @lelloman thanks for being patient and helping me.

Comment: np, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

One simply cannot add a local `AAR` dependency alike a `JAR` dependency.

It is required setup a local `flatDir` repository in the root project's `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        flatDir {
            dirs "libs"
        }
    }
}
```

Then one can reference the `AAR` almost alike any other dependency; notice the `@aar`:

```
implementation "com.acme:somelibrary:1.0.0@aar"
```

And most likely, you would also have to use `api` instead of `implementation` (in the library module)

... in order to expose the `ConstraintLayout` to the "library consumer" (which is the app module).

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it in the question that flatDir is already added to my root gradle file exactly the way you have mentioned it. Also 'api' did not work for me.

Comment: @Veeshal you could still `exclude` the `ConstraintLayout` from the `implementation` and explicitly add it directly into the app module's `dependencies`. the dependencies as you've posted them above are in every case wrong and might have little effect... the lower half of my answer nevertheless applies.

Comment: ConstraintLayout dependency in app module definitely works but I didn't want it to be included explicitly. Aar Library dependency should be automatically resolved when shared with anyone.

Comment: @Veeshal it probably won't be added unless declaring it. this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31994083/549372) shows an alternate way of doing so; but in general, it has to be declared (it might not only not know about the `ConstraintLayout`, but the whole `AAR`). just try with `./gradlew app:dependencies` to see what is even included.

Comment: If I include aar file from this library https://github.com/Veeshal/scratchCardLayout [choosen randomly] then I am not getting any error.